# error trying to train a model using ultralytics yolo 8 model

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, object-detection, yolo, yolov8

I am trying to train Yolo 8  using a sample data set as explained here: https://learnopencv.com/train-yolov8-on-custom-dataset/#The-Pothole-Detection-Dataset-to-Train-YOLOv8

The yaml file that used is as follow:

```
path: d:/MyData/Yolo8_tutorial/pothole_dataset_v8
train: 'train/images'
val: 'valid/images'

# class names
names:
    0: 'pothole'
```

and the code that I have is:

```
# Load the model.
model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt')
 
# Training.
results = model.train(
   data=pothole_yaml_file,
   epochs=1,
   name='yolov8n_v8_50e'
)
```

I am running this code on a jupyter notebook.

when I run this code, I am getting this error after 7 minutes that seems the application tries to run the training loop.

```
Validating d:\MyData\Yolo8_tutorial\runs\detect\yolov8n_v8_50e7\weights\best.pt...
Ultralytics YOLOv8.0.72  Python-3.9.0 torch-2.0.0+cu118 CUDA:0 (NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050, 3072MiB)
Model summary (fused): 168 layers, 3005843 parameters, 0 gradients, 8.1 GFLOPs




FileNotFoundError: Dataset 'pathole_data.ymal' for task=detect not found
```

What is the error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Say your yaml file name is pothole.yaml and it is placed in the root directory of the project where train.py file is located, then you need you pass data='pothole.yaml' as an argument in the model.train method.

**For Example:**

```
results = model.train(
data='pothole.yaml',
imgsz=512,
epochs=10,
batch=8,
device='0',
name=name)
```